# Hide action in django admin if they don't have permission

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I added an action in my admin pages that allows user to export selected records to an excel sheet. Now I need to be able to only allow some users to be able to export data. I have a `UserProfile` model that has a `can_export` boolean field.

How can I only show the "Export To Excel" action in django admin only if they have the `can_export` field set as True?

I have tried to find a way in admin.py to get the request object and do a IF statement before setting actions but have had no luck. I get a name'request' is not defined error of course.

```py
if request.user.get_profile().can_export:
    actions = [export_data()]
```

Comment: what happened after you do the IF statement? Keep showing the action or keep hiding the action?

Comment: It doesn't work: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: how about create a new custom permission for you action?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the FineManual (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/actions/):

```
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        ...

        def get_actions(self, request):
            actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
            if request.user.username[0].upper() != 'J':
                if 'delete_selected' in actions:
                    del actions['delete_selected']
            return actions
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for some users whose `can_export` is `True`, you can display **`export_data` admin action** by overriding [get_actions()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin, messages
from .models import UserProfile

@admin.register(UserProfile)
class UserProfileAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    actions = ["export_data"]

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if not request.user.get_profile().can_export:
            del actions["export_data"]
        return actions

    def export_data(self, request, queryset):

        # Export data

        messages.success(request, "Successfully data is exported!")
```